# Not able to reference models from django import

Tags: python, django

I am in the process of trying to get a module set up within a site I'm working on. I am working on building a Testimonials module and I believe I've got the code structure together properly although I'm not really sure(I am new to Django/Python but was told it was similar to RoR. I've not had much luck). I have gotten stuck with a Django not being able to recognize the module models when I import it and try and referencing it. So for example:

```
            from django.db import models
            from django.db.models import permalink
```

However line 2 throws an error because line 1 doesn't want to import properly. I've grabbed this code from tutorials and the books I've purchased seem to back up this structure. So I've done further research and I think I need to activate my module before I can start referencing it throughout the code. The models module is stuck in a loop of trying to load and trying to look at the same time. In theory my understanding is if I activate the module this stops happening.

So I'm told I need to use code similar to this in the terminal:

```
            python manage.py sql realtor/apps/testimonial/
```

However my response is:

```
            Error: App with label realtor/apps/testimonial/ could not be found. 
            Are you sure your INSTALLED_APPS setting is correct?
```

So I look at Installed Apps and as far as I can tell… I've set it up right:

```
            # project
            'realtor',
            'realtor.apps.blog',
            'realtor.apps.testimonial',
```

I am really stuck as I've no idea how to push forward and due to my lack of experience I don't even know this is my actual problem.

Thanks guys!

**UPDATE**

I also thought I'd share the error I am getting when browsing the site.

```
ImportError at /admin/
No module named models
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named models
Exception Location:     /Users/andrewkelly/Documents/Projects/1027_BRAD_BIRD/WORKING_BUILD/realtor/apps/testimonial/ad    min.py in <module>, line 2
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/andrewkelly/Documents/Projects/1027_BRAD_BIRD/WORKING_BUILD',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-    scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: What version of django are you using? EDIT nevermind, just noticed it's 1.4

Answer (score 0):

Is `realtor` an App? Maybe you must remove this line from your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Realtor needs to be in there. The folder structure has Realtor folder in the root folder.

I am pretty sure it needs to be there as several other aspects (none of which is dynamic. Just static pages that have views in the Realtor folder) runs with it setup as it currently is.

Comment: Thanks by your comment. Please try in the command line to exec `python` to go to `python` shell, and then try this `import django`, and also try `django.VERSION` to be sure what django version are you using. After that you can go to your project root, and exec the django shell `python manage.py shell` and once there try this `from django.db import models`. I'm thinking that something is happening with the django installation. Please let me know your results to see if I can help you with something more after that. Thanks.

Comment: I just realized I never replied back. Thank you for you help. We weren't able to get the application working and ended up switching to a PHP based app.

Thanks again for all your help.